# disable jquery auto close self closing tags

Tags: jquery

how i can disable auto close self closing tags and auto converting to lower case feature in jQuery 1.3.2 ?

it is necessary for me to keep Blog Service Tags on that's standard state , such as:

```
<BlogSky:Post Body>
```

that converted to:

```
<blogsky:post Body="">
```

or in other case change :

```
<a href="<BlogSky:Post HRef />"><BlogSky:Post Title /></a>
```

to:

```
<a href="<BlogSky:Post HRef />"><blogsky:post></blogsky:post></a>
```

Comment: how are you adding these controls?